# Progress Bar with JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to show a Progress Bar depending on the name. I have given the Progress Bars an id with the name and with a class "progressbar." For example, $('#John.progressbar') displays the Progress Bar for John. But, if I use the variable result instead nothing works.

```
 function progress(json,name){
     var result = "'" + "#" + name + "." + "progressbar" + "'";
     $('result').progressbar({
          value: json
     }); 
 }
```

When I do console.log it even shows the exact name but for some reason `$('result').progressbar` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the result variable, you are using `'result'` string...

```
var result = "#" + name + ".progressbar";
$(result).progressbar({
```

You wrote:

```
$('result')...
```

Notes:

- `#` is for id selector not for name selector.
- id is(should be) unique, no need the id selector a class
- `'` in `javascript` is for start-end strings indicator. it's just like `"` in `C#\java` or most other languages you're familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are just creating a string.

To select the element, you need to use:

```
var result = $("#" + name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the result-variable as the selector, if that is what you intend. You set the selector as a string with the text `result`. Try this instead:

```
 var result = "#" + name + ".progressbar";

 $(result).progressbar({
  value: json
 });
```